# How can I run a script as part of a Travis CI build?

Tags: python, travis-ci

As part of a Python package I have a script `myscript.py` at the root of my project and

```
setup(scripts=['myscript.py'], ...)
```

in my `setup.py`.

Is there an entry I can provide to my `.travis.yml` that will run `myscript.py` (e.g. after my tests)?

I've tried

```
language: python

python:
  - "2.7"

install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - pip install pytest

script:
  - py.test -v --color=yes --exitfirst --showlocals --durations=5
  - myscript.py some args
```

but get a "command not found" error.

I don't need (or really want) the script to be part of the test suite, I just want to see it's output in the Travis log (and, of corse, fail the build if it errors).

How can I run a package script as part of a Travis CI build?

Comment: `python myscript.py some args`?

Comment: @sobolevn: Doh! —  yep! That's an answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments (you need to call python):

```
language: python

python:
  - "2.7"

install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - pip install pytest

script:
  - py.test -v --color=yes --exitfirst --showlocals --durations=5
  - python myscript.py some args
```

(Prepending python in the last line.)

Aside: travis should have pytest preinstalled.

---

There's also an `after_success` block which can be useful in these cases (for running a script only if the tests pass, and not affecting the success of the builds) - often this is used for posting coverage stats.

```
language: python

python:
  - "2.7"

install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - pip install pytest

script:
  - py.test -v --color=yes --exitfirst --showlocals --durations=5

after_success:
  - python myscript.py some args
```