# Django on GAE - How to automatically 'migrate' on deploy?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, travis-ci

Django v1.11

Postgresql v9.6

Currently, I use 2 Google CloudSQL databases, one for development and one for production. Whenever I make changes to my models, I run `python manage.py migrate` to update the tables in the development database. This migration does not affect the production database, however.

Now, whenever I `git push` changes to my Django project, TravisCI automatically runs tests and deploys the code to Google App Engine. Currently, it runs on GAE flexible environment (so I can use Python 3.5)

What I want to have is for Travis or GAE to automatically run `python manage.py migrate` on the production database before `runserver`. However, I can't figure out how to run custom commands during a deploy.

I've tried looking around GAE and Travis documentation and adding scripts to `.travis.yml` and `app.yaml`, but to no avail.

As of now, anytime there is a model change, I have to migrate the production database locally in a very hacky way. Ideally, GAE will migrate at the beginning of every deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have seen this:

[Travis CI Script Deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment-v2/providers/script/)

A reference from a similar issue:

[How can I run a script as part of a Travis CI build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703325/how-can-i-run-a-script-as-part-of-a-travis-ci-build)

Also, consider a database migration tool embedded with your source code, Postgresql  is supported (something similar to FlywayDB migration ):

[Yoyo database migrations¶](https://ollycope.com/software/yoyo/latest/)